# Apply rules to growing window

Tags: r, for-loop, sliding-window

I want to loop through the dataframe `Out` using a window that:

1. Grows one increment at a time (so the rear of the window is fixed and the front of the window grows - window gets bigger)
2. At each increment, the following rules should be run over the window:

   ```
   if (mean(Speed_out) <= 0.152682)
   Behaviour <- Lying
   else if (Movement_Out == “left”) <= 20.8 && (mean(Speed_Out) >= 
   0.200921)
   Behaviour <- Grazing
   ```
3. If no rules are met then the window should grow one increment at a time until a rule is met.
4. Once a rule is met, all of the previous increments should be labelled with the `Behaviour` assigned to that rule above.
5. The next window should then start at the next element after where the last window terminated.
6. The initial window size should be adjustable (the window size at the start and after each terminated window).

**Notes:**

The units `(Movement_Out == “left”) <= 20.8` mean that if `"left"` occupies less than 20.8% of the window.

**Example:**

Here's a short example of the output I'd like from the data provided below where the starting window size was set to `4`:

```
    Speed_Out Movement_Out  Behaviour
1      0.220         left    Lying 
2      0.155         left    Lying
3      0.120      forward    Lying
4      0.090   non-moving    Lying   <== window terminates here
5      0.125   non-moving    Grazing <== new window starts here   
6      0.125   non-moving    Grazing
7      0.155   non-moving    Grazing
8      0.340      forward    Grazing
9      0.370      forward    Grazing <== window terminates here
10     0.185      forward    Grazing <== new window starts here
11     0.155        right    Grazing
12     0.220   non-moving    Grazing
13     0.220   non-moving    Grazing 
14     0.280   non-moving    Grazing <== window terminates here
15     0.215   non-moving    Grazing <== new window starts here
16     0.060        right    Grazing
17     0.340   non-moving    Grazing
18     0.555      forward    Grazing <== window terminates here
19     0.275        right    And so on..
20     0.215      forward
```

**Dataframe for your use**

```
Out <- structure(list(Speed_Out = c(0.22, 0.155, 0.12, 0.09, 0.125, 
0.125, 0.155, 0.34, 0.37, 0.185, 0.155, 0.22, 0.22, 0.28, 0.215, 
0.06, 0.34, 0.555, 0.275, 0.215, 0.185, 0.06, 0.245, 0.31, 0.345, 
0.375, 0.375, 0.87, 1.025, 0.405, 0, 0.185, 0.31, 0.155, 0.125, 
0.22, 0.375, 0.345, 0.345, 0.405, 0.31, 0.34, 0.245, 0.155, 0.19, 
0.22, 0.185, 0.12, 0.185, 0.155, 0.245, 0.31, 0.155, 0.155, 0.25, 
0.215, 0.09, 0.06, 0.245, 0.495, 0.495, 0.34, 0.28, 0.31, 0.28, 
0.25, 0.25, 0.185, 0.155, 0.25, 0.28, 0.28, 0.34, 0.215, 0.125, 
0.155, 0.34, 0.34, 0.09, 0.59, 1.71, 1.18, 0.185, 0.215, 0.185, 
0.185, 0.155, 0.19, 0.19, 0.19, 0.87, 2.045, 2.73, 1.585, 0.22, 
0.25, 0.435, 0.405, 0.405, 0.405, 0.715, 0.62, 0.37, 0.4, 0.185, 
0.375, 0.59, 0.525, 0.245, 0.495, 0.495, 0.68, 0.775, 0.25, 0.31, 
0.34, 0.28, 0.28, 0.25, 1.55, 2.695, 1.705, 1.21, 0.87, 0.25, 
1.52, 1.52, 0.405, 0.81, 2.08, 2.915, 1.705, 0.435, 0.22, 0.78, 
1.215, 0.84, 0.495, 0.495, 0.56, 0.375, 0.28, 0.715, 1.025, 0.495, 
0.65, 1.18, 1.09, 0.995, 0.87, 0.435, 0.125, 0.435, 0.555, 0.775, 
1.12, 1.555, 1.15, 0.25, 0.87, 0.93, 0.28, 0.31, 0.31, 0.375, 
0.78, 0.655, 0.53, 0.62, 0.525, 0.37, 0.555, 1.025, 0.655, 1.12, 
1.585, 0.715, 0.155, 0.28, 1.12, 2.11, 1.645, 0.715, 0.465, 0.84, 
0.81, 0.655, 0.84, 0.435, 0.28, 0.215, 0.93, 1.335, 0.65, 0.185, 
0.155, 0.34, 0.4, 0.37, 0.435, 0.405, 0.28, 0.28, 0.25, 0.25, 
0.745, 1.24, 0.805, 1.055, 1.085, 0.465, 0.375, 0.5, 0.59, 0.37, 
0.185, 0.34, 0.37, 0.435, 0.405, 0.06, 0.125, 0.25, 0.31, 0.405, 
0.78, 0.56, 0.215, 0.495, 0.87, 1.025, 0.62, 0.405, 0.405, 0.405, 
0.31, 0.215, 0.465, 0.435, 0.34, 0.275, 0.215, 0.25, 0.22, 0.22, 
0.125, 0.245, 0.34, 0.31, 0.37, 0.31, 0.31, 0.245, 0.185, 0.25, 
0.22, 0.22, 0.31, 0.28, 0.22, 0.28, 0.53, 0.655, 0.375, 0.19, 
0.405, 0.435, 0.28, 0.215, 0.77, 0.96, 1.865, 1.83, 0.495, 0.655, 
1.615, 1.395, 0.31, 0.31, 0.25, 0.28, 0.34, 0.34), Movement_Out = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("forward", 
"left", "non-moving", "right"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Speed_Out", 
"Movement_Out"), row.names = c(NA, 283L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have to say that this has been less trivial than I expected. My answer is ugly and most likely not optimal, but it seems to work.

There seem to be a few spots where even when the rest of the data was taken into account, none of the conditions were met, so the behaviour for those stayed at NA.

```
library(dplyr)

# Create id variable used to join results later
Out <- Out %>%
  mutate(id=row_number())

# Initial window size
window_size <- 4

# Initialize variables used in loop
w <- window_size
i<-1
window_cnt<-1
out_behaviour <- data.frame(id=as.numeric(), Behaviour=as.character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

while (i <= NROW(Out)){

  print(paste0("Row: ", i, ", Window Size: ", w))

  df <- Out[i:(i+w-1),] %>%
    mutate(mean_sp=mean(Speed_Out),
           mvmt=sum(ifelse(Movement_Out=="left",1 ,0))/NROW(.)) %>%
    mutate(Behaviour=case_when(mean_sp <= 0.152682 ~ "Lying",
                               mvmt <= 0.208 & mean_sp >= 0.200921 ~ "Grazing",
                               TRUE ~ as.character(NA)),
           window_nr=window_cnt)

  if (!all(is.na(df$Behaviour))){
    i<-w+i
    w<-window_size
    out_behaviour <- rbind(out_behaviour, df %>% select(id, Behaviour, window_nr))
    window_cnt<-window_cnt+1
  } else {
    if (w<=NROW(Out)-i){
      w<-w+1
    } else {
      w<-window_size
      i<-i+1
    }
  }

  rm(df)
}

# Join Behaviour column bacl to original data frame
Out <- left_join(Out, out_behaviour, by="id") %>% select(-id)

# Clean up workspace
rm(i, w, window_size, window_cnt, out_behaviour)
```

And the first 20 outputs

```
   Speed_Out Movement_Out Behaviour window_nr
1      0.220         left     Lying         1
2      0.155         left     Lying         1
3      0.120      forward     Lying         1
4      0.090   non-moving     Lying         1
5      0.125   non-moving   Grazing         2
6      0.125   non-moving   Grazing         2
7      0.155   non-moving   Grazing         2
8      0.340      forward   Grazing         2
9      0.370      forward   Grazing         2
10     0.185      forward   Grazing         3
11     0.155        right   Grazing         3
12     0.220   non-moving   Grazing         3
13     0.220   non-moving   Grazing         3
14     0.280   non-moving   Grazing         3
15     0.215   non-moving   Grazing         4
16     0.060        right   Grazing         4
17     0.340   non-moving   Grazing         4
18     0.555      forward   Grazing         4
19     0.275        right   Grazing         5
20     0.215      forward   Grazing         5
```

I know the code is a mess, so let me know if it needs some extra commenting.

Comment: I'd recommend you also add a print(i) and print(w) inside the loop to see the progress and make sure you are not stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Excellent - this work great! It's easy enough to add rules also if need be. Being a novice - where would you recommend placing the print statements? Many thanks indeed.

Comment: @PharmR I've updated my answer for the code to be a bit cleaner and I've added the print statement for you.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: My pleasure. It was an interesting problem to solve :)